# Can assigning a value to a field in an if statement in Groovy cause the database to update the record

Tags: database, groovy, scripting

I have a simple online interface for writing Groovy scripts that get incorporated into a larger piece of software. I was bouncing between on project in VB6 and the other in Groovy and so accidentally used one equals sign (which VB6 does for if statements) where I meant to use a double-equals in Groovy.

Could assigning a value to a database field in an if statement in this fashion actually update all of the records for which the rest of the if conditions were true?

Comment: Depends on your ORM and transaction handling, but yes.

Comment: @doelleri Does the assignment just evaluate to true inside the if statement then? I would have expected the assignment in the if statement to be a syntax error because an if statement must boil down to a boolean, doesn't it? I Googled the heck out of this, but I seem to be the only person on the face of the planet to have done anything like this; I'm curious how/why Groovy was designed this way, as mixing test conditions with assignments feels a bit messy to me. There must be an upside.

Comment: I initially misread your question and thought it was related to automatic persistence of dirty values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's assignment operator will return the variable just assigned. If this is inside a statement expecting a boolean it will be evaluated according to Groovy's truthiness. We can see this in the Groovy console with some asserts:

```
groovy:000> assert (foo = 1)
===> null
groovy:000> assert (foo = 0)
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError:
assert (foo = 0)
            |
            0
```

or with an `if` statement:

```
groovy:000> if ((foo = 'bar')) {
groovy:001>   println "Assignment was true!"
groovy:002> }
Assignment was true!
```

Note that you need the double parentheses for this to "work" because without them you will get a compile error trying to parse it:

```
groovy:000> if (foo = 'bar') {
groovy:001>   println "Assignment was true!"
groovysh_parse: 2: expecting ')', found '=' @ line 2, column 9.
   if (foo = 'bar') {
           ^
```

It can be pretty insidious. It has some use cases though, like a while loop that iterates on a method's return value until it returns false:

```
while (data = getData()) {
    doWork(data)
}
println "Done with all the data"
```

Comment: The final example of why this is a useful language feature was especially helpful for understanding.